# Issue with If Statement not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an issue with an if logic statement that I cant seem to figure out and am looking for someone wiser than me to point out the error of my ways.

Below is my code:

```
$sql = "select count(id) from tempaddress where postcode='".$values['PostCode']."'";
$rs = CustomQuery($sql);
$data = db_fetch_array($rs);

print_r($data);
if ($data > 0)
{
    //Redirect to Address Selection Page
    $cid=$keys['CompanyId'];
    header("Location: UpdateAddress_edit.php?editid1=".$cid);
    exit();
}

else echo "<script>alert('No Addresses Found.  Please Contact Administrator')</script>";
```

What this is supposed to do is look up how many results are found and if the answer is >0 then it takes it to next page, if not it gives you a popup message.

The count function works, but for some reason, even if the result is 0, it still takes the process to next page, see here http://prntscr.com/58949d, I have put a false post code in, and it should say, no!

Can anyone see what is going wrong, or point out a way to use if record exists then {}?

I am using PHP with MS Access.

Comment: what does `$data` contain?

Comment: what does it prints `print_r($data)`?

Comment: try if($data != NULL).. if this is durpal

Comment: Yes look at top left of this screenshot, this is for a postcode i know exists http://prntscr.com/589858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, alias your expression:
`$sql = "select count(id) as addressCount from tempaddress where postcode='".$values['PostCode']."'";`

Then use it in the if statement
    if ($data['addressCount'] > 0){
    ...
    }
    else{
    }

Answer (score 0):

It should be like -

```
if ($data['Expr1000'] > 0)
```

Comment: thanks, tried that but then all entries (valid or otherwise) go to alert message

Comment: Yes look at top left of this screenshot, this is for a postcode i know exists http://prntscr.com/589858

Comment: updated the answer.. if everytime the key remains same

Answer (score 0):

try `if($data[0] > 0 )`since you're fetching as array

Comment: thanks, tried that but then all entries (valid or otherwise) go to alert message